# Gedit warning: GtkScrolledWindow is mapped but visible child GtkScrollbar is not mapped

Tags: 13.10, 14.04, gedit

When I use gedit, there is warning shown:

```
(gedit:3166): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkScrolledWindow 0x236cd10 is mapped but visible child GtkScrollbar 0x2307ab0 is not mapped
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstall overlay-scrollbar .I hope it will fixed your problem .

Comment: This does not fix the problem on a clean install of 14.04.3 updated to 2016 January 2.

Answer (score 8):

It was a bug in overlay-scrollbar which has been fixed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/overlay-scrollbar/+bug/1086494) at launchpad. It has been fixed.

So just run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install overlay-scrollbar
```

Comment: If it's a fixed bug at the time of this answer-post (17 May 2014), then wouldn't have standard software updates of ubuntu fix it by this comment (21 May 2014)? It seems that there is a bug in the software updates related to this because a re-installation *of the same version* `overlay-scrollbar` solved the problem. Weird!

Comment: what this error means? Is there any change in data alignment or mixing in between rows,when this error is shown by gedit.

Comment: This does not fix the problem on a clean install of 14.04.3 updated to 2016 January 2.

Answer (score 5):

Until the update has been revised past 14.04, go ahead and reinstall the package:
`sudo apt-get --reinstall install overlay-scrollbar`

Comment: This does not fix the problem on a clean install of 14.04.3 updated to 2016 January 2.

Answer (score 0):

Did'nt work for me either, on a fresh install of ROS & Ubuntu 14.04 using a package developed and distributed by ROS.org. @dmuk can we just ignore the messages and proceed without concern?  Thanks.